# nfs error 'no locks available' after update to 16.10

Tags: nfs, 16.10

I use `vagrnat` with virtualbox vm and nfs synced folders to run `django` app and after update to 16.10 `vagrant up` fails on provision step with error:

```
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/vagrant/proj >/dev/null && /home/vagrant/venv/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

Copying '/home/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/LICENSE'

...
OSError: [Errno 37] No locks available
```

I tried to reinstall `nfs-kernel-server, nfs-common, liblockfile1, libnfsidmap2` but with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Someone in systemd land decided that starting nfs shouldn't start the statd service which nfs uses to provide locks. So, your fix should be simple, on the host machine:

```
sudo systemctl enable rpc-statd  # Enable statd on boot
sudo systemctl start rpc-statd  # Start statd for the current session
```

You don't even need to reboot, just launch vagrant after doing that.

Thanks systemd!

Comment: You don't even need to reload vagrant after that. Just run the rpc-statd start command, and the lock service would be available even for the already launched vagrant machines.

Comment: Cool, thanks bro! It work for me , vagrant enviroment and django app :D
ubuntu 16.04 Elementary Os

Comment: Wow man. Thanks. This was killing me for a while, since in my particular case it wasn't always giving me obvious errors. Had to strace an sqlite file to get here.